# How can I remove the extra vertical space above the first equation in a cases environment?

Tags: spacing, cases, aiaa

This problem seems to be related to the AIAA class that I have to use to submit the paper that I am writing, as I cannot reproduce it with other classes.

The latest `Aiaa.cls` class file can be retrieved from [here](http://arc.aiaa.org/userimages/ContentEditor/1367257604835/AIAA_REVTeX41.ZIP) (link found at [this](https://www.aiaa.org/SecondaryTwoColumn.aspx?id=26241#Journal_Manuscript_Submission) page).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{AIAA}
\ProcessOptions

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{S}\left( u \right) = 
\begin{cases}
x\left( u \right) = a_{x} \cdot u\\
y\left( u \right) = a_{y} \cdot u\\
z\left( u \right) = a_{z} \cdot u
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Visualization of the problem:

[image]

How can I get rid of that extra white space/ extra long upper curly brace?

Comment: I don't have  this problem with your code, which I had to modify: the class is `aiaa-tc`. There must be something else in your real code.

Comment: I also did not get this problem.  I compiled with aiaa.cls V2.4 (22 FEB 1999) and had to download dropping.sty (V0.12, JUN 12 1997).

Comment: @Bernard I compiled the code posted and the result is in the image. how did you came to the `aiaa-tc` class?

Comment: With `AIAA` I have an error message: `cls unknown`. So I read the documentation. How comes *you* can compile?

Comment: @Bernard I have dowloaded the aiaa.cls file

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes please see the updated link I provided. your cls file is an old version. Aiaa now distributes version 4.1

Comment: I can reproduce your error on the first pass.  But then, the compile breaks if I try to recompile...  Very strange.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes if it helps, I use TexWorks with pdfLaTeX. I can recompile with no issues :/

Comment: not relevant to the question, but with the content of the display as shown, there is absolutely no need for `\left` and `\right`.